# Building C++ file with g++ in Windows not working as .bat

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, batch-file

Good morning,

I am a new user of Windows (+10 years using Linux) and for some reason I have to compile a C++ program. I do not have a big experience in debugging in Windows, but I am eager to understand what I do wrong.

I use MinGW with g++ and different libraries, particularly one called libjpeg.

When I compile & build the file in a PowerShell using the following command, everything works fine, and my C++ code gives me the expected results.

```
g++ -o imageProcessing imageProcessing.cpp -lgdi32 -Dgmic_use_jpeg -I'C:\GnuWin32\include' -L'C:\GnuWin32\lib' -ljpeg
```

When I use the exact same command in a .bat file, or directly in my C++ editor (geany), I have this error:

```
imageProcessing.cpp:6:21: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jpeglib.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

It doesn't find the jpeglib.h.

The correct path were set in the environmental variables.

The libjpeg I use allows me to open/save jpeg pictures when I use the CImg library. It can be found here:

[Jpeg for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/jpeg.htm)

Here is a very simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jpeglib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float number;
    cout << "Enter a number: "; 
    cin  >> number;
}
```

Let's call this test.cpp and its location is: `C:\Users\Rémi\Documents\Image_Procesing\C++\testCImg`

Here is what I've added in my environmental variables path: `C:\GnuWin32\lib;C:\GnuWin32\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;`

Here is my test.bat: `g++ -o test test.cpp -lgdi32 -Dgmic_use_jpeg -I'C:\GnuWin32\include' -L'C:\GnuWin32\lib' -ljpeg`

test.bat is also located in: `C:\Users\Rémi\Documents\Image_Procesing\C++\testCImg`

the .bat fail is the following:

```
C:\Users\Rémi\Documents\Image_Procesing\C++\testCImg>g++ -o test test.cpp -lgdi32 -Dgmic_use_jpeg -I'C:\GnuWin32\include
' -L'C:\GnuWin32\lib' -ljpeg
test.cpp:3:21: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jpeglib.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

I spent all my day yesterday trying to figure it out, and I am limited by my Windows knowledge.
If someone could help me, I would appreciate it very much.

Thank you.

Comment: just guess - try use -I'C:/GnuWin32/include'

Comment: I'm not convinced we have enough to go on here. Can you abstract away the library, presenting a narrow testcase with a single include that you put in a specific directory, telling us what that directory is, showing that it's in the include path, then showing the BAT fail to find it? This is potentially an interesting question but it doesn't look reproducible in its current form.

Comment: @Sergey : it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : I've edited my original post. Is it enough ?

Comment: Does it help to replace the single quotes with double?  Argument tokens in Windows traditionally use the `"` character.  I'm thinking the single quotes are being interpreted as part of the path names, resulting in the "no such file or directory" errors.  That would explain why it works in PowerShell, though, as single quotes are valid there.  See if you have better luck with `g++ -o imageProcessing imageProcessing.cpp -lgdi32 -Dgmic_use_jpeg -I"C:\GnuWin32\include" -L"C:\GnuWin32\lib" -ljpeg`

Comment: @rojo : Pfff, that was it.... Thank you very much. Learning the hard way.

Comment: @RémiM If you don't mind, I'll post that as an answer and have you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument tokens in Windows traditionally use the `"` character. I'm thinking the single quotes are being interpreted as part of the path names, resulting in the "no such file or directory" errors. That would explain why it works in PowerShell, though, as single quotes are valid there.

See if you have better luck with this:

```
g++ -o imageProcessing imageProcessing.cpp -lgdi32 -Dgmic_use_jpeg -I"C:\GnuWin32\include" -L"C:\GnuWin32\lib" -ljpeg
```

Comment: Asking GCC to print out the search paths would have revealed this.

Answer (score 2):

When you have include path problems, ask GCC to tell you what it's using.

In the below example, you can clearly see that it's searching for a location `'test'` and ignoring it for not existing.

You can then deduce that, as mentioned elsewhere, the single quotes are wrong in Batch. At that point you'd give `"test"` a go and achieve success.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\lightness>g++ -E -x c++ - -v -I'test'
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/gcc-4.7.1/configure --build=mingw32 --enable-language
s=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --enable-threads=win32 --enable-libgomp --enabl
e-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-sp
ecific-runtime-libs --with-gnu-ld --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --disab
le-symvers --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --disable-werror --prefix=/mingw3
2tdm --with-local-prefix=/mingw32tdm --enable-cxx-flags='-fno-function-sections
-fno-data-sections' --with-pkgversion=tdm-1 --enable-sjlj-exceptions --with-bugu
rl=http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.1 (tdm-1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-I' ''\''test'\''' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/cc1plus.exe -E -quiet -v -I 'test'
-iprefix c:\mingw32\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/ - -mtune=i386 -march=i386
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw32\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../..
/../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/inc
lude/c++"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/inc
lude/c++/mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/inc
lude/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/inc
lude"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../
../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/inc
lude-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw32/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/.
./../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "'test'"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw32\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++
 c:\mingw32\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/mingw32
 c:\mingw32\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/backward
 c:\mingw32\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include
 c:\mingw32\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include
 c:\mingw32\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include-fixed
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
```

Comment: Something like this is what I meant by a testcase. :)